# Add attachments to a document in a document library

Tags: document, attachment, sharepoint-2013, document-library, sharepointdocumentlibrary

Is there a way to add attachments to documents in a SharePoint document library? Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no way to add attachment to document item. 
You may consider using [document sets](http://blogs.technet.com/b/vedant/archive/2010/04/21/using-the-document-set-feature-in-sharepoint-2010-part-1.aspx) if you want to group documents in single item.